# Confused on how to move through an Array (getFeed)

Tags: php, templates, modx, modx-revolution

I don't know MODX, and the docs aren't clicking. I am using getFeed, https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/getfeed, and i have the following code:

```
[[!getFeed?
   &url=`http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/123456789.rss`
   &tpl=`rssTpl`
   &limit=`3`
]]
```

I use this, I get an array, so I know it works, but I'm not sure how to loop through this data to display. It just looks like a `var_dump()` otherwise.

I am having trouble finding what to do with the `rssTpl`. Where does it go?.

My `.tpl` file:

```
<div class="entry">
    <p><a href=[[+link]]>[[+title]]</a></p>
    <p>[[+description]]</p>
</div>
```

Also the template this goes in is static, and displays correctly. Do I have to something similar to the `.tpl` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rssTpl` refers to a chunk. You say it's a `.tpl` file, but you'll need to make sure it's a chunk in MODX as well. Adding a chunk is done in the Elements tab of the manager sidebar.

When it's there, I believe your template should work fine with getFeed.

According to the [example](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/getfeed/getfeed.adding-a-twitter-feed) you seem to be using, Twitter did stop supporting those RSS feeds, so that might also be getting in your way.

Comment: Thank you. That was the thing I couldn't figure out. The whole, everything is done through the dashboard and in the database is different. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help!